# How to fix "package is in very bad inconsistent state"?

Tags: package-management

The Synaptic Package Manager shows an error message whose details contain:

> E: gnome-control-center-data: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration
> E: gnome-control-center: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

[image: screenshot of error message]

Please explain what happen in my Ubuntu and how to fix that, thank you

Comment: @K7AAY im still newbie, can you explain what is just happen?

Comment: We were not looking over your shoulder, so we do not know "what is just happen." There are many possibilities, but only one useful solution: Use apt to reinstall the package. Try: `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center-data`. If it does not work, then edit your question to include the complete output.

Comment: @user535733 thank you, my problem already finish by your answer

Answer (score 1):

This was answered [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151842/how-to-fix-package-is-in-very-bad-inconsistent-state#comment1915111_1151842) by [user535733](https://askubuntu.com/users/19626/user535733). The solution was to reinstall the `gnome-control-center-data` package using the command:

```bsh
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center-data
```

---

In general, if Synaptic or another tool says a package needs to be reinstalled, this can be achieved with the `install` action of `apt` (or `apt-get`, or `aptitude`), so long as the `--reinstall` option is also passed.

Without `--reinstall`, the package wouldn't be installed again because if the package manager believes it is already installed. (If it was automatically installed, it would be marked as manually installed, but this would not actually fix any missing or corrupted files from it.)